# Missing POST parameters in AJAX call result in undefined index warnings in PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using AJAX for the first time so I write a code and I followed a tutorial, but when I try to send my post with ajax I am getting undefined index and I really don´t know why, I tried to search answer hear but since I am using AJAX and javascript for the first time, the code there didn´t tell me anything.
Here is my code, I would be really greatful for any help, thank you.

js method

```
function post() {
    var name = $('meno').val();
    var priez = $('priezvisko').val();
    $.post( "aktualizuj.php", {
        'meno': name,
        'priezvisko': priez
    },
        function (data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
        );
}
```

html form...

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prihlasenie.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="meno" >Meno:</label><input type ="text" name="meno" id="meno" value ="meno" ><br>

    <label for="priezvisko" >Priezvisko:</label><input type ="text" id="priezvisko" name="priezvisko" value ="priezvisko" ><br>
<input type="button" value="ulozZmeny"  onclick="post()" >
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this where I should get from ajax/javascript

```
session_start();
require "pripojenie.php";


    $meno = $_POST['meno'];

    $priezvisko = $_POST["priezvisko"];
    $login = $_SESSION['login'];
```

Comment: I am sorry I added my code as a picture because I coudln´t format the code properly but i can´t see those images anywhere :(

Comment: can you see those pictures ?

Comment: no, no pictures. Just paste the (relevant parts of your) code into the text area, then select all of the code and press ctrl+k for formatting it as a code block.

Comment: where can I edit this topic ?

Comment: [Update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34566711/edit) with the relevant code, and no images please.

Comment: Under the question text there are the tags  for the question (javascript,php,ajax in this case) and below that there are several links, one of them should be [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34566711/edit)

Comment: And what's the actual error/warning/notice message you get?

Comment: it´s should be okay now.. I folowed the tutorial but I am getting undefined index meno and priezvisko  in the last part of code where I am trying to put thos POST from ajax to php variables.. I also tried some stuff I found in differnet questions here but it didn´t work as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jquery doesn't serialize key:value pairs where value is [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), i.e.

```
$.post(url, { foo:undefined });
```

results in jquery not sending any POST parameter.

The problem is because of the following lines,

```
var name = $('meno').val();
var priez = $('priezvisko').val();
```

This would look for an *element* `meno` and an *element* `priezvisko` (and then their values) as if you had a document like

```
<p>
  <meno>...</meno>
  <priezvisko>...</priezvisko>
</p>
```

But you're looking for elements that have `meno`/`priezvisko` as value of their id attribute(s):

```
var name = $('#meno').val();
var priez = $('#priezvisko').val();
```

You should nevertheless check the existince of the parameters in your php script. Nothing prevents another script/bot/user to invoke your script with different parameters or no parameters at all.
see also:

- http://docs.php.net/isset
- http://docs.php.net/filter

Comment: You have the wrong code twice as often as the correct code in your post ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK Sorry, didn't know what else to put there. :)

Comment: May I edit the answer (and the question)? Because I find the question more interesting than expected (jquery not serializing key:undefined at all)

Comment: @VolkerK sure, go ahead. :)

Comment: Can I ask one more thing ? Is there any easy way in this code to refresh content of my page but not the whole page ? because that changing are saved in my database, how can I replace the contet without refreshing the page ?

Comment: @eraz A simple Google search will help you go in the right direction. [Change contents of a page without refreshing](https://www.google.co.in/#q=change+contents+of+a+page+without+refreshing).